# Text color does not change when hover

Tags: css

I have the following code that will change the state of a button when the text is changed, Even though the back style is applied successfully the color of the text will not change.

Code:

```
.links li {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 5%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background-image: url("../images/button_background.jpg");
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.links li:hover{
    color: black;
    background-image: url("../images/button_background_hover.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Add your HTML, do you have a tags in list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the sample. I made two samples- one with  tag and one without.

```
<ul class="links1">
    <li><a href="">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">link 4</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="links">
    <li>li 1</li>
    <li>li 2</li>
    <li>li 3</li>
    <li>li 4</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/rx3avr7r/

Comment: If you are finding this useful, please, accept as an answer.